# Являются ли глаголы "имел" и "считался" однородными сказуемыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сказуемые, однородные-члены

**Город имел всего лишь два фундаментальных здания и считался посёлком для кочевников-скотоводов.**
Нужна ли между ними запятая?

Answer (score 1):

**Од­но­род­ны­ми** на­зы­ва­ют­ся два или несколь­ко чле­нов пред­ло­же­ния, ко­то­рые вы­сту­па­ют в одной и той же син­так­си­че­ской функ­ции (т. е. иг­ра­ют в пред­ло­же­нии одну роль; обычно отвечают на один и тот же вопрос), от­но­сят­ся к од­но­му и тому же слову и свя­за­ны друг с дру­гом со­чи­ни­тель­ной или бес­со­юз­ной свя­зью.
[**Однородные члены предложения**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/723-27_odnorodnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Однородные сказуемые (**имел, считался**) относятся к одному подлежащему (**город**), между собой они связаны соединительным союзом **и**, поэтому запятая не ставится.

***Церковь имеет*** очень узнаваемый внешний вид **и считается** одним из символов города.

***Город имел*** всего лишь два фундаментальных здания **и считался** посёлком для кочевников-скотоводов.

Answer (score 0):

Являются ли глаголы “имел” и “считался” однородными сказуемыми?

Да, такое вполне допустимо. Но запятая в любом случае не нужна. Здесь нет двух основ, предложение не является сложносочиненным, поэтому запятая перед не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

1. Это однородные сказуемые, ибо они относятся к одному и тому же подлежащему: город.